# Django + Virtualenv: manage.py commands fail with ImportError of project name

Tags: django, importerror, manage.py

This is blowing my mind because it's probably an easy solution, but I can't figure out what could be causing this.

So I have a new dev box and am setting everything up. I installed virtualenv, created a new environment for my project under `~/.virtualenvs/projectname`

Then, I cloned my project from github into my projects directory. Nothing fancy here. There are no `.pyc` files sitting around so it's a clean slate of code.

Then, I activated my virtualenv and installed Django via pip. All looks good so far.

Then, I run `python manage.py syncdb` within my project dir. This is where I get confused:

```
 ImportError: No module named projectname
```

So I figured I may have had some references of projectname within my code. So I grep (ack, actually) through my code base and I find nothing of the sorts.

So now I'm at a loss, given this environment why am I getting an ImportError on a module named `projectname` that isn't referenced anywhere in my code?

I look forward to a solution .. thanks guys!

Comment: Have you checked sys.path to make sure everything looks valid? I'd make sure also that django.__file__ is what you expect (within your virtualenv).

Comment: sys.path looks pretty valid. It includes my virtualenv directory and the usual python directories.

django.__file__ outputs django's __init__.pyc within my virtualenv directory, as well. No luck here then :/ Thanks for your help so far - any other suggestions?

Comment: Is `projectname` exactly (modulo suffix) the name of the directory the project is in? Wild guess, but I know Django does *some* things with the current directory… Also, what is trying to import `projectname`? Do you get a traceback? If not, try running with `py manage.py --traceback syncdb` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks David, it looks like the issue was with the folder name being the same as the project name. Not sure WHERE it got the projectname as I never really set it anywhere  but I will enjoy the fact that it works now. Can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is projectname exactly (modulo suffix) the name of the directory the project is in? Wild guess, but I know Django does some things with the current directory…

Also, what is trying to import projectname? Do you get a traceback? If not, try running with `py manage.py --traceback syncdb` and see what happens.